# Change PHP Settings When Running a Command

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php

I want to run a command on a shared server, it requires some PHP settings to be set but I can't change them inside `php.ini` because I can't access the ini file that the terminal reads, so I decided to change those settings when running the command, but I need two settings to be changed.
For doing that, I know I can use:

```
php -d [setting]
```

For example:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on composer update
```

So how do I change two settings within the same command?, I tried something like this:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on, memory_limit=512M composer update
```

But it isn't working, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `-d` for each options you need to change:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on -d memory_limit=512M composer update
```